# Как устранить возрастающую задержку при отправке данных через EDGE (2G)?

Tags: android, сеть, gprs

Eсть клиент-серверное приложение под андроид. Клиент под *Android* с периодичностью раз в 100 ms отправляет UDP пакет (около 100 байт) на сервер. Одним полем данных пакета является `timestamp`. Время на клиенте и сервере синхронизировано. В качестве сети используется EDGE мобильного оператора. На сервере  каждую секунду сравниваем `timestamp` полученный от клиента с текущим временем и получаем следующую картину:

```
Время клиента 17:30:01, время сервера 17:30:01
Время клиента 17:30:02, время сервера 17:30:02
Время клиента 17:30:03, время сервера 17:30:04
Время клиента 17:30:04, время сервера 17:30:05
Время клиента 17:30:05, время сервера 17:30:06
Время клиента 17:30:06, время сервера 17:30:07
Время клиента 17:30:07, время сервера 17:30:08
Время клиента 17:30:08, время сервера 17:30:11
Время клиента 17:30:09, время сервера 17:30:11
Время клиента 17:30:10, время сервера 17:30:11
Время клиента 17:30:11, время сервера 17:30:20
Время клиента 17:30:12, время сервера 17:30:20
Время клиента 17:30:13, время сервера 17:30:20
Время клиента 17:30:14, время сервера 17:30:21
Время клиента 17:30:15, время сервера 17:30:22
Время клиента 17:30:16, время сервера 17:30:23
Время клиента 17:30:17, время сервера 17:30:24
Время клиента 17:30:18, время сервера 17:30:25
Время клиента 17:30:19, время сервера 17:30:26
Время клиента 17:30:20, время сервера 17:30:27
Время клиента 17:30:21, время сервера 17:30:28
```

После возникновения лагов на 8й и 11й секунде пакеты начинают передаваться с 20й секунды. В итоге получаем статическую задержку в получении пакетов в 7 секунд. При последующем  возникновении лагов эта задержка существенно возрастает. Притом очередь исходящих сообщений формируется на клиенте, т.к. если клиент отключить от сети запоздавшие пакеты приходить не будут. Ищу ответ как сделать, чтобы сгенерированные пакеты во время лага не отправлялись в сети или не копились в буфере. Нужно получать максима. Пробовал изменять значение  `SO_SNDBUF` в опциях сокета на клиенте вплоть до нуля, но эффекта не было.

Comment: На других устройствах или с другим типом соединения не пробовали?

Comment: Какие то странные 100ms как за них проходит 1s ? и вы timestamp получаете какой то системной функцией каждый раз ?

Comment: 1) пробовал - картина примерно такая же.
2) выборку специально сделал  1 раз в секунду чтобы было наглядно видно проблему.

Comment: а может быть такое, что между получением времени клиента и собственно пакетом от сервера есть какой-то ещё код, например, отправка логов или какие-то не нужные метрики? тогда все очень вписывается.

Comment: к сожалению нет. Для теста специально делал только прием и вывод нужного поля из UDP пакета. Мне кажется это особенность работы исходящей очереди сообщений на мобильном клиенте. Пока ожидается доступность сети EDGE или выполняется ретрансмит ранее переданных пакетов очередь копится. Суть в том, чтобы максимально укоротить данную очередь (удалить все старые неотправленные пакеты). Дропы не так важны как своевременность данных. К сожалению, не нашел техник как определять длину текущейю исходящей очереди, а уж тем более как влиять на неё.

Comment: Читаем вики: EDGE - протокол основанный на таймслотах. Такие протоколы не могут позволить себе передавать короткие пакеты. Потому как им надо заполнить полностью один слот и потом ждать следующего. Соответственно применяется GTP (GPRS Tunneling Protocol) инкапсуляция на канальном уровне (osi 2).  Никакие настройки на сетевом (osi 3) не могут повлиять на его поведение. Можно разве что рыть в направлении возможности программного взаимодействия с канальным уровнем.

Comment: Короткие пакеты может и не может, но пакеты по 100 байт попадают в таймслот. Что объясняет практический  тест когда пакеты передаются и принимаются вовремя. Принципиальный вопрос где возникает очередь во время лага, как её опустошить, и как мониторить возникновение лага??

Comment: Выскажу догадку, ничем не обоснованную, что все где-то на сервере в какой-то очереди накапливается. Поставить сниффер и посмотреть если реально из сети с опозданием приходит.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы выявить причину попробуйте использовать тот же клиент по Wi-Fi.

- Если и по Wi-Fi будет такая же ситуация, значит проблема где-то на уровне вашей программы или системного софта.
- Если по Wi-Fi задержек не будет, то это будет означать что проблема в работе EDGE, и что вы, скорее всего, не можете её устранить.